# EventHandler in Core project fails to find user from RazorPages project to send message via SignalR hub

Tags: domain-driven-design, razor-pages, asp.net-core-signalr

There are 3 project: Core, Persistence (EfCore with SQL Server) and UI (Razor Pages).

When a User updates a record a DomainEvent is added in the Core project and published in the Persistence layer on commit, but by then the User no longer exists in the HttpContext and the server throws an error because User is null.

The event MemberAddedEvent is added when a new Group Member is added.

```
public class Group 
{
    public List<Contact> Members { get; set; }

    public List<DomainEvent> DomainEvents { get; private set; }
    
    public void AddMember(Contact newMember)
    {
        Members.Add(newMember);
        var memberAddedEvent = new MemberAddedEvent(newMember);
        DomainEvents.Add(memberAddedEvent);
    }
}
```

The event is published in the DbContext on Save:

```
        public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken
                = new CancellationToken())
        {
            /*
               truncated for brevity
            */

            var entitiesWithEvents = ChangeTracker
                .Entries()
                .Select(e => e.Entity as BaseEntity<int>)
                .Where(e => e?.DomainEvents != null && e.DomainEvents.Any())
                .ToArray();

            foreach (var entity in entitiesWithEvents)
            {
                var events = entity.DomainEvents.ToArray();
                entity.DomainEvents.Clear();
                foreach (var domainEvent in events)
                {
                    await _mediator.Publish(domainEvent, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }

            return result;

        }
```

The UI has a service IUserAccesssor which returns the HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.

```
    internal class UserAccessorService(IHttpContextAccessor context) : IUserAccessorService
    {
        public string GetUserName()
        {
            return context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
```

The MemberAddedEventHandler passes the notification message to the SignalR MessageHub to display the pretty little toast notification for the User.

Most of the time this happens quickly enough that the user still exists in the HttpContextr, but sometimes it does not.

How do I persist the username? Do I need to add it to the initial request to AddMember and pass it to the DomainEvent?

```
public class AddMemberCommand : IRequest<AddMemberCommandResponse>
{
    /*
        member properties here
    */ 

    public string UserName { get; set; }

}

public abstract class DomainEvent : INotification
{
    public DomainEvent(string userName)
    {  
        UserName = userName;
    }
    public string UserName { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I have solved this in the persistence layer. I added a User property to the DomainEvent abstract class.

```
public abstract class DomainEvent : INotification
{
    public string User { get; set; }
}
```

I was already tracking the username to record who made changes to a record in the database

```
        public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken
                = new CancellationToken())
        {
            /*
               truncated for brevity
            */

            var entitiesWithEvents = ChangeTracker
                .Entries()
                .Select(e => e.Entity as BaseEntity<int>)
                .Where(e => e?.DomainEvents != null && e.DomainEvents.Any())
                .ToArray();

            foreach (var entity in entitiesWithEvents)
            {
                var events = entity.DomainEvents.ToArray();
                entity.DomainEvents.Clear();
                foreach (var domainEvent in events)
                {
/*
User Name added here to the Domain Event
*/
                    domainEvent.User = userService.UserName();
                    await _mediator.Publish(domainEvent, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }

            return result;

        }
```

Then read by the EventHandler and passed to the notification service

```
    internal class MemberAddedEventHandler(INotifyService notifyService) : INotificationHandler<MemberAddedEvent>
    {
        public async Task Handle(MemberAddedEvent notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            NotificationMessage message = new NotificationMessage(
                user: notification.User,
                message: $"Member added: {notification.Member.FirstName}",
                state: "Success"
                );

            await notifyService.NotifyUserAsync(message);
        }
    }
```